# What are Hash Functions?

Tags: hashing

I am trying to read up on System Design, and several articles talk about how a Primary Key for the input data, which is a string, can be passed into a Hash function and we get a number. This can eventually be used in consistent hashing, or other hashing techniques. I get the idea of the hash function, where if you pass some input you will always (ideally) get the same output. But how are hash functions written? I can simply designate a number to each alphabet, and using that I can convert a string to a number. Would that be a valid hash function that I can use in system design?

Comment: "Would that be a valid hash function that I can use in system design?" – Define "valid"? It certainly satisfies the definition of "hash function" and thus *is* a "hash function".

Comment: It's somewhat surprising that you did not see implementation examples in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function ...

Comment: I did obviously see the wiki article, but wiki articles tend to get too much into details and math. I start reading those, and then I need to start reading other articles to understand this explanation and so on. I am probably less smarter than the average person, so I needed a simpler explanation in context of system design to get started.

Comment: I voted to reopen because the only question in the StackExchange network about this I could quickly find is https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/70089/how-is-the-hash-for-a-file-calculated . And this indeed has a focus on technical details. An answer that lays out the purpose and quality characteristics of hash codes (what makes a good hash, for what purposes and why would you care) would be a valueable addition.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A hash function is a function that, in general, takes an arbitrary-size string and returns a fixed-sized number. Thus, it can be seen as compressing lots of information into a small fingerprint. For most use cases, this fingerprint should be “random”, that is: have no clear resemblance to the input. But different inputs should produce different outputs.

Your idea of assigning numbers to each character is good (that's how computers work anyway), but now we want to turn that long sequence of numbers into a single fixed-sized number.

So, very broadly speaking, a hash function will keep some state, then loop over all numbers or blocks in the input, and combine the state with the input. This is typically done via the XOR operation, which is a lot like an addition without carry.

```py
def trivial_hash(input_numbers: list[int]) -> int:
  state = 12345  # initial value
  for num in input_numbers:
    state = state ^ num
  return state
```

Unfortunately, this is a really bad hash function. Most numbers in the input are going to be small, or have other patterns. For example, the ASCII text encoding uses 7 bits, leaving the highest bit in a byte always zero. If a bit is always going to be zero, then that bit in the hash output won't carry useful information.

So we need to extend our hash function so that each bit can affect any other bit in our state as well. Using left-shifts `<<` or right-shifts `>>` can help, but only work by fixed amounts. In “fast hash functions” that are often used for hash tables, multiplication with a large prime is a good choice. For this toy example, let's use the small prime `13` though. However, multiplication can only affect leftward/higher bits, and can't distribute information downwards. So we typically also have to add a right-shift.

```py
def slightly_better_hash(input_numbers: list[int]) -> int:
  state = 12345 # initial state
  for num in input_numbers:
    state = state ^ x  # mix current value into the state
    state = state * 13  # distribute bits leftwards
    state = state ^ (state >> 16)  # distribute bits rightwards
  return state
```

This general architecture is typical for a fast hash functions, but there are massive differences in the exact operations used, and in the choices for constants. For example, the constant used for multiplication should be large, typically a prime number, and distribute the bits of the input value widely. Many hash functions use multiple stages to mix the bits around in order to achieve better quality. Chris Wellons has a fun blog post about [prospecting for hash functions](https://nullprogram.com/blog/2018/07/31/), where he tries out different constants.

As a practical example of a real hash function, consider the FNV-1a hash function, here with the constants for the 64-bit version:

```py
def fnv_1a(input_bytes: list[byte]) -> int:
  state = 14695981039346656037
  for x in input_bytes:
    state = state ^ x
    state = state * 1099511628211
  return state
```

<sup>Disclaimer: The use of Python syntax is purely for illustration purposes. This code does not work. FNV-1a relies on fixed-size unsigned multiplication. To simulate this with Python's arbitrary-size integers, we'd need to truncate the input back to 64 bits after each multiplication.</sup>

There are other possible constructions for hash functions as well. Instead of using bit twiddling to shuffle bits around, some hash functions use a lookup table to map each byte to a different byte value.

### Relationship to RNGs

There is a direct relationship between hash functions and pseudo-random number generators. A simple PRNG can be constructed out of any hash function by repeatedly hashing the state:

```
rng_state = hash(12345)

def random() -> int:
  rng_state = hash(rng_state)
  return rng_state
```

or by hashing a counter:

```py
rng_state = 0

def random() -> int:
  rng_state += 1
  return hash(rng_state)
```

Conversely, good RNGs generally include a bit mixing function that can be used in a hash function.

Here is an example of the Xoshiro128** PRNG that is my go-to choice for Monte Carlo simulations etc:

```c
// Xoshiro256** from <https://prng.di.unimi.it/> is public domain (CC-0)

static inline uint64_t rotl(const uint64_t x, int k) {
    return (x << k) | (x >> (64 - k));
}

static uint64_t s[4];  // must be seeded to non-zero state

uint64_t next(void) {
    const uint64_t result = rotl(s[1] * 5, 7) * 9;

    const uint64_t t = s[1] << 17;

    s[2] ^= s[0];
    s[3] ^= s[1];
    s[1] ^= s[2];
    s[0] ^= s[3];

    s[2] ^= t;

    s[3] = rotl(s[3], 45);

    return result;
}
```

This function relies entirely on bit-shifts to distribute bits around, and only uses multiplications for extracting the next output from the state. However, it has a 4× larger state than the output so that it is not possible to predict the sequence of generated numbers from the output alone (unlike with the toy RNG constructions I showed above). This could be converted into a hash function by xor-ing an input into the state at each step, and ignoring the result until the end. For initializing the state, the SplitMix64 RNG is typically used.

### Some hash functions have security properties

Cryptographic hash functions are broadly similar to normal hash functions, but they have very stringent security goals. These goals are also good for normal hash functions, but there they are just a matter of quality. For example, flipping any single bit in the input should have a 50% chance of flipping each output bit, and you shouldn't be able to predict which. Cryptographic hash functions must not be reversible – you shouldn't be able to trace the bits of a hash back to a plausible input. A cryptographic hash function achieves this through a sophisticated and well-analyzed bit mixing approach.

Security properties of hash functions are important for digital signatures, but also for content-addressable storage systems such as the Git version control system. These use cases will fail if there is a hash collision. In contrast, data structures like hash tables are built to deal with collisions.

Cryptographic hash functions are sometimes considered “slow” – they use more complicated techniques for mixing bits, whereas “fast” hash functions try to produce the hash in as few CPU cycles as possible. But in practice, some cryptographic hash functions are “fast enough”, in particular since modern CPUs provide hardware acceleration for common cryptographic hash functions like SHA-2.

SipHash is an interesting example of a hash function that is used for its security properties, but is not a cryptographic hash function. SipHash is often used to defend against hash table denial-of-service attacks. For example, if a web application uses hash keys provided by a user, then the user could try to provide many keys that collide when hashed with the server's hash function. Common hash table designs then fall back to a linear search through the hash table, which is comparatively slow. SipHash is a keyed hash function. Essentially, the initial state of the hash function is set to a secure random value so that attacker's can't predict collisions.

Cryptographic hash functions should not be confused with key-stretching or password hashing functions that are deliberately designed to be difficult to brute-force. Some password hashing functions achieve this through multiple rounds of a simpler hash function, others by requiring the use of a large lookup table. Argon2 is a state of the art password hashing function with different variants and tunable parameters for different use cases. Internally, it uses multiple iterations of the Blake2 hash function, which is in turn based on the ChaCha stream cipher (an encryption algorithm), which is also used by SipHash. It is common in cryptography to build upon existing functions since these are generally well-analyzed and can be assumed to be secure – developing a completely novel hash function is risky.

For comparison with the previous bit mixing functions, here is the function used by ChaCha20 to prepare each 512-byte input block before adding it into the current state. This looks inefficient and complex, but a lot of that is amortized for large inputs.

```c
#define ROTL(a,b) (((a) << (b)) | ((a) >> (32 - (b))))
#define QR(a, b, c, d) (            \
    a += b,  d ^= a,  d = ROTL(d,16),   \
    c += d,  b ^= c,  b = ROTL(b,12),   \
    a += b,  d ^= a,  d = ROTL(d, 8),   \
    c += d,  b ^= c,  b = ROTL(b, 7))
#define ROUNDS 20

// 10 loops × 2 rounds/loop = 20 rounds
for (int i = 0; i < ROUNDS; i += 2) {
    // Odd round
    QR(x[0], x[4], x[ 8], x[12]); // column 0
    QR(x[1], x[5], x[ 9], x[13]); // column 1
    QR(x[2], x[6], x[10], x[14]); // column 2
    QR(x[3], x[7], x[11], x[15]); // column 3
    // Even round
    QR(x[0], x[5], x[10], x[15]); // diagonal 1 (main diagonal)
    QR(x[1], x[6], x[11], x[12]); // diagonal 2
    QR(x[2], x[7], x[ 8], x[13]); // diagonal 3
    QR(x[3], x[4], x[ 9], x[14]); // diagonal 4
}
```

<sup>From *[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salsa20#ChaCha_variant)*, available under CC-BY-SA 3.0 (sorry, couldn't find a better source quickly)</sup>

In some use cases such as content fingerprinting, we don't want small changes in the input to drastically change the output. Instead, we want similar inputs to create similar fingerprints, but without being able to get the full input back. This is still a hash function because it compresses arbitrary-size input into a fixed-sized output, but it is not suitable for use cases such as digital signatures or hash tables. In the case of images, such content fingerprints are sometimes similar to creating a very low-resolution thumbnail from the original, but with added normalization to account for cropping, rotation, or color filters.

Comment: Thank you! This connects a few pieces of the puzzle together for me. I was a bit surprised by how many articles just use a hash function in the design as a black box that takes in something and generates a convenient output that can be used, but none talks about sample hash functions. The above gives me some idea and helps me understand what I am reading!

Comment: @JörgWMittag I edited the answer to account for some of your feedback.